# Adding Customer Specific Record in Master Table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design, multi-tenant

I have the following table designed already.

> Now the new requirement is i need to show some Category for all the
>   tenants. Also each tenant should able to add their new Category into
>   the Master Category. So they can see all master + their specific
>   categories

**Tenant Table**

```
TenantId
Name
```

**Group Table**

```
GroupId
Name
```

**Category Table**

```
CategoryId
Name
```

**TenantXCategory**

```
TenantId
CategoryId
```

What changes i can do in above tables to achieve it? I tried this below

Modified Category table to below.

**Category Table**

```
CategoryId
Name
TenantId NULL // This indicates tenant specific category
```

Add a unique key for TenantId and Name

Then queried

```
SELECT *
  FROM Category where TenantId = 1
  UNION
SELECT *
  FROM Category where TenantId IS NULL
```

> But the problem is if two tenant only want to see a particular
>   Category, I need to add a new row with other TenantId in Category
>   table. This mean i am creating duplicate entry in a lookup table. Any
>   suggestion to achieve the new requirement?

Comment: Does a tenant freely choose what Category they want to see? Or is there a limited access to some Categories? In other words, do you need to distinguish between what a tenant is *permitted* to see and what they *choose* to see?

Comment: @AndriyM by default they can see all master tenant records. If they feel something needs to be added, they can add. But that record needs to be tenant specific. So others should not see this newly added record, specific to other tenent

Comment: So, just to make sure that I've got this right: by default, a tenant-specific category is visible *only* to the tenant that created it. When a tenant wants to add other tenants' categories to his/her visible category list, he/she is permitted to choose *any* category of those. Is that correct?

Comment: @AndriyM, Nope. Those are tenant secret information. He should not choose from other tenant, but should be able to add his own. Here only i am thinking how to do without adding a same record, if it added by another tenant. In that case, can we do mapping? I am in confusion :(

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. Please take a look at my answer then (hopefully I've understood the question correctly this time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a tenant A may see:

- (1) master categories,
- (2) categories that belong to tenant A,
- (3) categories which belong to another tenant and which the other tenant explicitly allowed tenant A to see

Your present schema seems to satisfy the requirements. In particular, the first two rules can indeed be implemented using a nullable `TenantId` column in the `Category` table, where NULL would stand for a master category and a non-NULL value would reference the creator/owner of the category and thus signify a tenant-specific category. (I might rename the column to something like `OwnerTenantId` for better clarity, but that might be just me.)

To retrieve only master categories or those that belong to the specified tenant, you could use the query you've posted in your question or this one (which will probably yield an identical execution plan to your query's):

```
SELECT
  CategoryId,
  CategoryName,
  CASE
     WHEN TenantId = @TenantId    THEN 'Mine'
     WHEN TenantId IS NULL        THEN 'Master'
  END AS Ownership
FROM Category
WHERE TenantId = @TenantId
   OR TenantId IS NULL
;
```

To implement the third rule, you could use your `TenantXCategory` table to store categories available to tenants *in addition* to those that are accessible using the first two rules. That is, if tenant M permits tenant N to see some of tenant M's categories, the categories' Ids would be inserted into `TenantXCategory` along with tenant N's Id.

So, to query all categories available to a particular tenant, you could do something along the lines of the following:

```
SELECT
  c.CategoryId,
  c.CategoryName,
  CASE
     WHEN c.TenantId = @TenantId    THEN 'Mine'
     WHEN c.TenantId IS NULL        THEN 'Master'
     WHEN tc.CategoryId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Someone else''s'
  END AS Ownership
FROM Category c
LEFT JOIN TenantXCategory tc
  ON tc.CategoryId = c.CategoryId AND tc.TenandId = @TenantId
WHERE c.TenantId = @TenantId
   OR c.TenantId IS NULL
   OR tc.CategoryId IS NOT NULL
;
```

Comment: This looks perfect. I use your idea and when we create a new category that was already defined by other client in the system, I add only mapping in TenantXCategory. This prevents duplicate in Category table too. :) Great idea.

Comment: Is it possible to add some tenant specific additional column in that Category? So i can able to show more columns based on a client. I have no idea about achieve those :(

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me again. Adding what kind of column and where? If you mean you want to add tenant specific information from the `Tenant` table, you could just join `Tenant` to `Category` or to `TenantXCategory` or to both (which means you would need to join it twice), although in this case joining to `TenantXCategory` would be somewhat trickier than to `Category`.

Comment: For example one tenant want category information like CategoryId, Name, CategoryDesc, IsRequiredApproval fields for his form. Now another tenant wants CategoryId,Name,AlternateName. In this case CategoryDesc, IsRequiredApproval, AlternateName columns are specific to each client. Do i need to keep adding this TenantSpecific columns in Category table? Or is any way to handle this dynamic columns for tenant?

Comment: Oh, I see. There are at least two issues at the moment. #1, I'm not sure what to suggest at this point and "it depends" may not be an answer you were looking for. However, #2, your new question sounds to me, well, like a *new* question. :) Honestly, it may indeed require a more elaborate answer than just a quick suggestion in a comment. The question itself may need to be more elaborate too. (E.g. how many tenant-specific columns can there be? can various tenants be expected to share the same set of columns? etc. Those might actually be questions you should first answer yourself before asking.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be adding additional categories, you should *probably* have an identifier to distinguish between master and user-defined categories.

```
CREATE TABLE CategoryType (
    [CategoryTypeID] int primary key identity,
    [Description]
)

CREATE TABLE Category (
    [CategoryID] int primary key identity,
    [CategoryName] nvarchar(max)
    [CategoryTypeID] int
)

/*  CategoryTypes
    1    Master
    2    User-defined  */
```

Show categories for a specific tenant

```
SELECT *
FROM TenantXCategory txc
JOIN Tenant t
    ON t.TenantID = txc.TenantID
JOIN Category c
    ON c.CategoryID = txc.CateoryID
WHERE t.TenantName = N'user1909604'
    -- AND c.CategoryTypeID = 1 -- Only show master categories
    -- AND c.CategoryTypeID = 2 -- Only show user-defined categories
    -- AND c.CategoryID in (1, 2) -- Only show specific categories
```

To add a category for a user, store the category in your cross reference table. If the category doesn't exist, you'll have to add it to the category table first.

```
INSERT TenantXCategory (TenantID, CategoryID)
SELECT @TenantID, @CategoryID
```

--

Unless you're storing who created the category (for auditing purposes), this should work. If not, I misunderstood your question and you should clarify what you're trying to do.